# How to add popup on D3.js visualization (tree nodes)

Tags: javascript, d3.js

We are using d3.js tree (d3.tree()) to render org chart visualization. It is very similar to
https://observablehq.com/@julienreszka/d3-v5-org-chart

I want to display small popup over the node on click/mouseover of some button. e.g. clicking on person image display small popup with some more actions. So user can click on any of the link in popup.

Is there any recommended approach to achieve it in D3js?

Answer (score 1):

You can attach the event listener for `click` or `mouseover` when you update Nodes. For instance, the example you mentioned has this piece of code:

```
// Updating nodes
const nodesSelection = centerG.selectAll('g.node')
  .data(nodes, d => d.id)

// Enter any new nodes at the parent's previous position.
var nodeEnter = nodesSelection.enter().append('g')
  .attr('class', 'node')
  .attr("transform", function(d) {
    return "translate(" + source.x0 + "," + source.y0 + ")";
  })
  .attr('cursor', 'pointer')
  .on('click', function(d) {
    if ([...d3.event.srcElement.classList].includes('node-button-circle')) {
      return;
    }
    attrs.onNodeClick(d.data.nodeId);
  })
```

If you check the `onclick` here, it is calling the `NodeClick` method; you will need to change `NodeClick` or, if you want a `mouseover` method, add an `.on('mouseover')` event. If you want to target the image in node, then add the event at this place:

```
nodeUpdate.selectAll('.node-image-group')
  .attr('transform', d => {
    let x = -d.imageWidth / 2 - d.width / 2;
    let y = -d.imageHeight / 2 - d.height / 2;
    return `translate(${x},${y})`
  })


nodeUpdate.select('.node-image-rect')
  .attr('fill', d => `url(#${d.id})`)
  .attr('width', d => d.imageWidth)
  .attr('height', d => d.imageHeight)
  .attr('stroke', d => d.imageBorderColor)
  .attr('stroke-width', d => d.imageBorderWidth)
  .attr('rx', d => d.imageRx)
  .attr('y', d => d.imageCenterTopDistance)
  .attr('x', d => d.imageCenterLeftDistance)
  .attr('filter', d => d.dropShadowId)
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer! I understood the implementation to add event listener on btns inside org chart node. Addition to that, what I want is to display popup/modal with some more options/links. each node would show the popup when we click/mouse hover on specific region(btn/image) inside node.  the popup would adjacent to each node.  I did not find any way to display popup on D3js visualization.

Comment: You can use tooltip on d3..There are many examples out there. Tooltip is a type of popup only and can be assigned greater width and height e.g https://observablehq.com/@benoldenburg/patterns-tooltip